# How to create selenium chrome docker containers that have .p12 browser certificate

Tags: docker, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, docker-compose

I have a selenium grid setup with chrome on my ubuntu vm.
I want to test an app with a certificate generated from a test CA system with .p12 extension.

How can I import the CA root certificate in chrome programmatically ?

Currently ran docker container using

```
- docker run -d -p 4444:4444 --shm-size="2g" selenium/standalone-chrome:4.8.0-20230123
```

My script is able to launch the browser but app page is not loaded as the certificate on this browser is missing.

Is there's any way to create new chrome image using my own certificate?